# ¿Cómo puedo rellenar un Entry automáticamente con información que se encuentra en la base de datos?

Tags: python-3.x, base-de-datos, tkinter, sqlite3

Muy buen dia compañeros.
Lo que necesito es que al introducir el codigo y presionar "Consultar" se rellene el nombre correspondiente automaicamente. Por ejemplo, si introduzco el código 2001, se debe de escribir automaticamente "Evaporador 1 Ton" en el Entry Nombre
[image: Lo que necesito es que al introducir el codigo y presionar "Consultar" se rellene el nombre correspondiente automaicamente. Por ejemplo, si introduzco el código 2001, se debe de escribir automaticamente "Evaporador 1 Ton" en el Entry Nombre]

¡De antemano muchas gracias!

Para agregar un plus, me gustaría que a información de se autocompletara automáticamente sin necesidad de presionar el botón "Consultar".
Creo que tengo el programa necesario para ello pero no se como adaptarlo a mi programa principal.
!Muchas gracias nuevamente! Espero puedan ayudarme.
Este es mi programa principal:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import datetime

class Product:
    # connection dir property
    db_name = 'database5.db'
    
    def __init__(self, window2):
        global frame
        # Initializations 
        self.wind = window2
        self.wind.title('Nuevo Producto')

        # Creating a Frame Container 
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registrar nuevo producto',font= ("",18,))
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, pady = 10)

        # code Input
        Label(frame, text = 'Código: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.code = Entry(frame)
        self.code.focus()
        self.code.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        # Name Input
        Label(frame, text = 'Nombre: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
        self.name = Entry(frame)
        self.name.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

        # cantidad Input
        Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
        self.cantidad = Entry(frame)
        self.cantidad.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        self.cantidad.insert(0,'1')
        
        # Button Add Product 
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar Producto', command = self.add_product).grid(row = 7, columnspan = 2, sticky= W + E)
        ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Consultar', command = self.cons_product).grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W + E)

        # Output Messages 
        self.message = Label(text = '', fg = 'green')
        self.message.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)

        # Table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 24, columns=('1','2','3','4','5','6'))        
        self.tree.grid(row = 5, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('1', text = 'Código', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('2', text = 'Cantidad', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('3', text = 'Responsable', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('4', text = 'Fecha', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('5', text = 'Tipo', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('6', text = 'Destino', anchor = CENTER)

        self.tree.column("#0",anchor="center", minwidth=255, width = 255, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("1", anchor="center", minwidth=120, width = 120, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("2", anchor="center", minwidth=120, width = 120, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("3", anchor="center", minwidth=285, width = 285, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("4", anchor="center", minwidth=190, width = 190, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("5", anchor="center", minwidth=190, width = 190, stretch=NO)
        self.tree.column("6", anchor="center", minwidth=195, width = 195, stretch=NO)

        # Buttons
        ttk.Button(text = 'ELIMINAR', command = self.delete_product).grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W + E)
        ttk.Button(text = 'EDITAR', command = self.edit_product).grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W + E)

        # Filling the Rows
        self.get_products()

    # Function to Execute Database Querys
    def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
        with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
            conn.commit()
        return result

    # Get Products from Database
    def get_products(self):
        # cleaning Table 
        records = self.tree.get_children()
        for element in records:
            self.tree.delete(element)
        # getting data
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY id DESC'
        db_rows = self.run_query(query)
        # filling data
        for row in db_rows:
            self.tree.insert('', 'end',values=(row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7]), text = (row[1]))
            
    # User Input Validation
    def validation(self):
        return len(self.name.get()) != 0 and len(self.code.get()) != 0 and len(self.cantidad.get()) != 0 

    def add_product(self):
        global frame
        self.hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.fecha = self.hoy.strftime('%d/%m/%Y  %I:%M:%S %p' )
        #Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar(frame, value = self.fecha), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 6, column = 1)
        self.tipo = ('STOCK')
        self.resp = ('YARVA ↑')
        self.destino = ('ALMACÉN')

        if self.validation():
            query = 'INSERT INTO product VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parameters =  (self.name.get(), self.code.get(), self.cantidad.get(), self.resp, self.fecha, self.tipo,self.destino)
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.message['text'] = '{} añadido'.format(self.name.get())
            self.name.delete(0, END)
            self.code.delete(0, END)
            #self.cantidad.delete(0, END)
        else:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor ingrese nombre, código y cantidad'
        self.get_products()

    def delete_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
           self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor, seleccione producto a eliminar'
            return
        self.message['text'] = ''
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        query = 'DELETE FROM product WHERE Nombre = ?'
        self.run_query(query, (name, ))
        self.message['text'] = '{} eliminado '.format(name)
        self.get_products()

    def edit_product(self):
        self.message['text'] = ''
        try:
            self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            self.message['text'] = 'Por favor, seleccione producto a editar'
            return
        name = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['text']
        old_code = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][0]
        cantidad = self.tree.item(self.tree.selection())['values'][1]
        self.edit_wind = Toplevel()
        self.edit_wind.title = 'Editar producto'
        # New Name
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo nombre:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        new_name = Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = name))
        new_name.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        # New code
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nuevo código:').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
        new_code= Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = old_code))
        new_code.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

        # New cantidad
        Label(self.edit_wind, text = 'Nueva cantidad:').grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        new_cantidad= Entry(self.edit_wind, textvariable = StringVar(self.edit_wind, value = cantidad))
        new_cantidad.grid(row = 4, column = 2)

        Button(self.edit_wind, text = 'Confirmar', command = lambda: self.edit_records(new_name.get(), name, new_code.get(), old_code, new_cantidad.get(), cantidad)).grid(row = 5, column = 2, sticky = W)
        self.edit_wind.mainloop()
    
    def edit_records(self, new_name, name, new_code, old_code, new_cantidad, cantidad):
        query = 'UPDATE product SET Nombre = ?, Código = ?, Cantidad = ? WHERE Nombre = ? AND Código = ? AND Cantidad = ?'
        parameters = (new_name, new_code, new_cantidad, name, old_code, cantidad)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = '{} actualizado'.format(name)
        self.get_products()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window2 = Tk()
    window2.geometry('1600x700+0+0')
    application = Product(window2)
    window2.mainloop()
```

---

El otro programa que les comento, que introduce la información automaticamente al terminar de escribir del código es el siguiente:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(1, 1)
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=360, height=600)
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

codigocarga = tk.StringVar()
entrycodigo = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=codigocarga, font=("",24), justify="center")
entrycodigo.pack()
descripcioncarga = tk.StringVar()
entrydescripcion = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=descripcioncarga, width=28, font=("",24), justify="center")
entrydescripcion.pack()
entrycodigo.focus_set()

def on_text(*args):
   
    text = entrycodigo.get().lower()
    descripcioncarga.set("")

    if text == "1001":
        print("Evaporador 1 Ton Inverter Frikko")
        descripcioncarga.set("Evaporador 1 Ton Inverter Frikko")

    elif text == "1002":
        descripcioncarga.set("Condensador 1 Ton Inverter Frikko")
        print("Condensador 1 Ton Inverter Frikko")
codigocarga.trace_add("write", on_text)
root.mainloop()
```

---

En este caso tambien extraeria la informacion de la base de datos y no desde el mismo programa
Muchas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo hice algo parecido, pero sin usar POO, quizás te pueda orientar un poco. Soy nuevo en programación y no entiendo bien tu código, pero acá va el ejemplo que hice yo.

Primero te copio todo el código, y después voy a la parte que necesitas, así se entiende bien todo.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import sqlite3



#--------------Funciones--------------

def conexionBBDD():


    conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    
    try:
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Usuarios")

        cur.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            Name VARCHAR(50),Lastname VARCHAR(50),
            Password VARCHAR(16),
            Address VARCAHR(30),
            Comments VARCHAR(100))
            ''')
        mb.showinfo("DDBB", "BBDD correctly created.")

    except:
        mb.showwarning("Warning", "The BBDD already exists.")


def salirAplicacion():

    valor=mb.askquestion("Exit", "Are you sure you want to exit?")

    if valor =="yes":
        root.destroy()

def limpiarCampos():

    miID.set("")
    miNombre.set("")
    miApellido.set("")
    miPass.set("")
    miDirec.set("")
    cuadroComent.delete(1.0, END)

def crear():
    try:

        conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        

        varUsuarios = (miNombre.get(), miApellido.get(), miPass.get(), miDirec.get(), cuadroComent.get("1.0", END))
                
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Usuarios VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", varUsuarios)
        
        conn.commit()
        
        mb.showinfo("BBDD", "Record inserted successfully")
    
    except:
        mb.showwarning("Error")

def leer():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE ID=" + miID.get())

    elUsuario=cur.fetchall()

    for i in elUsuario:

        miID.set(i[0])
        miNombre.set(i[1])
        miApellido.set(i[2])
        miPass.set(i[3])
        miDirec.set(i[4])
        cuadroComent.insert(1.0, i[5])
    
    conn.commit()

def actualizar():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    varUsuarios = (miNombre.get(), miApellido.get(), miPass.get(),
                   miDirec.get(), cuadroComent.get("1.0", END))
    
    cur.execute("UPDATE Usuarios SET Name=?, Lastname=?, Password=?, Address=?, Comments=?" +
                 "WHERE ID=" + miID.get(), (varUsuarios))
    
    #cur.execute("UPDATE Usuarios SET Name='" + miNombre.get() + 
    #            "', Lastname='" + miApellido.get() + 
    #            "', Password='" + miPass.get() + 
    #            "', Address='" + miDirec.get() + 
    #            "', Comments='" + cuadroComent.get("1.0", END) + 
    #            "'WHERE ID=" + miID.get())
    
    conn.commit()
    
    mb.showinfo("BBDD", "Record updated successfully")

def eliminar():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("DELETE FROM Usuarios WHERE ID=" + miID.get())

    conn.commit()

    mb.showinfo("BBDD", "Record deleted successfully")


#--------------Root--------------

root=Tk()
root.title("Practice")

barraMenu = Menu()

root.config(menu=barraMenu, width=300, height=300)

TNR = font.Font(family="Times New Roman", size=11)

#--------------Menu--------------

bbdd = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="BBDD", menu=bbdd)
bbdd.add_command(label="Connect", command=conexionBBDD)
bbdd.add_separator()
bbdd.add_command(label="Exit", command=salirAplicacion)


edit = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit)
edit.add_command(label="Erase Fields", command=limpiarCampos)

crud = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="CRUD", menu=crud)
crud.add_command(label="Create", command=crear)
crud.add_command(label="Read", command=leer)
crud.add_command(label="Update", command=actualizar)
crud.add_command(label="Delete", command=eliminar)

helps = Menu(barraMenu, tearoff=0)
barraMenu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helps)
helps.add_command(label="Welcome")
helps.add_command(label="Documentation")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Report Issue")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="View License")
helps.add_command(label="Privacy Statement")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="Chek for Updates")
helps.add_separator()
helps.add_command(label="About")


#--------------Frame 1--------------
frame = Frame()
frame.pack()

miID=StringVar()
miNombre=StringVar()
miApellido=StringVar()
miPass = StringVar()
miDirec = StringVar()


cuadroID = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miID)
cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroID.config(fg="magenta2")

cuadroNombre = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miNombre)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroNombre.config(fg="red")

cuadroApellido = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miApellido)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroApellido.config(fg="green")

cuadroPass = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miPass)
cuadroPass.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroPass.config(fg="blue")
cuadroPass.config(show="*")

cuadroDirec = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miDirec)
cuadroDirec.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroComent = st.ScrolledText(frame, width=19, height=8, font=TNR)
cuadroComent.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroComent.config(fg="cyan2")




IDLabel = Label(frame, text="ID: ", font=TNR)
IDLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
IDLabel.config(fg="magenta2")

nombreLabel = Label(frame, text="Name: ", font=TNR)
nombreLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
nombreLabel.config(fg="red")

apellidoLabel = Label(frame, text="Lastname: ", font=TNR)
apellidoLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
apellidoLabel.config(fg="green")

PassLabel = Label(frame, text="Password: ", font=TNR)
PassLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
PassLabel.config(fg="blue")

direcLabel = Label(frame, text="Address: ", font=TNR)
direcLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)

comentLabel = Label(frame, text="Comments: ", font=TNR)
comentLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="e", padx=10, pady=10)
comentLabel.config(fg="cyan2")


#--------------Frame 2--------------


frame2 = Frame()
frame2.pack()


botonCrear=Button(frame2, text="Create", font=TNR, command=crear)
botonCrear.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

botonLeer = Button(frame2, text="Read", font=TNR, command=leer)
botonLeer.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

botonUpdate = Button(frame2, text="Update", font=TNR, command=actualizar)
botonUpdate.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

botonBorrar = Button(frame2, text="Delete", font=TNR, command=eliminar)
botonBorrar.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)


#--------------Fin--------------


root.mainloop()
```

Si lo copias y lo ejecutas, vas a ver que se abre la ventana principal. Para conectar con la base de datos, abrís el menú, donde dice `BBDD`, y clickeas en `Connect`.

Una vez conectada, para insertar datos en la base de datos (valga la redundancia), completas los campos requeridos, no hace falta completar el ID, ya que es la llave primaria y se rellena y autoincrementa automáticamente. Podes agregar las veces que quieras para probar. Fíjate también que en el menú `Edit`, está la opción de `Erase Fields`, que borra los campos.

Luego, si quieres buscar o consultar sobre alguna persona de la BBDD, solo debes introducir el número de `ID`, y luego clickear en el botón donde dice `Read`, y automáticamente se van a rellenar los campos.

Ahora, este es el código que se encarga de eso.

Primero creo la función `leer`. Y le digo que cuando se ejecute, seleccione y rellene los campos requeridos.

```
def leer():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Usuarios.sqlite")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE ID=" + miID.get())

    elUsuario=cur.fetchall()

    for i in elUsuario:

        miID.set(i[0])
        miNombre.set(i[1])
        miApellido.set(i[2])
        miPass.set(i[3])
        miDirec.set(i[4])
        cuadroComent.insert(1.0, i[5])
    
    conn.commit()
```

Luego creo las variables a las que llamo en la función :

```
miID=StringVar()
miNombre=StringVar()
miApellido=StringVar()
miPass = StringVar()
miDirec = StringVar()


cuadroID = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miID)
cuadroID.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroID.config(fg="magenta2")

cuadroNombre = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miNombre)
cuadroNombre.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroNombre.config(fg="red")

cuadroApellido = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miApellido)
cuadroApellido.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroApellido.config(fg="green")

cuadroPass = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miPass)
cuadroPass.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroPass.config(fg="blue")
cuadroPass.config(show="*")

cuadroDirec = Entry(frame, font=TNR, textvariable=miDirec)
cuadroDirec.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

cuadroComent = st.ScrolledText(frame, width=19, height=8, font=TNR)
cuadroComent.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
cuadroComent.config(fg="cyan2")
```

Y luego al botón `Read` le paso el comando de la función `leer`:

```
botonLeer = Button(frame2, text="Read", font=TNR, command=leer)
botonLeer.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Espero que puedas entenderlo y usarlo como ejemplo para tu código.

Saludos!

Comment: PD: si te sale bien, que espero y seguro que si, pasa tu código completo por acá, así lo analizo, gracias!